# How to filter a nested array with another array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array that I need to filter by skills, the user is selecting the skills and I need the results to match the entire filter, not just any of them.

```
[
{bio: ""
community_role: ""
display_name: ""
email: ""
facebook: ""
first_name: "sophia"
headshot: ""
instagram: ""
job_title: ""
last_name: ""
linkedin: ""
mentee: false
mentor: true
organization_name: ""
skills: [
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 398, category_id: 7, skill: "Running - casual"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 415, category_id: 8, skill: "Conflict resolution"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 436, category_id: 8, skill: "Interviewing"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 3, category_id: 1, skill: "Advising"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 87, category_id: 2, skill: "Risk management"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 15, category_id: 1, skill: "Decision making"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 9, category_id: 1, skill: "Communication"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 391, category_id: 7, skill: "Physical fitness"}
{user_id: 7, skill_id: 414, category_id: 8, skill: "Conflict management"}
]
twitter: "twitter.link"
user_id: 1
},
{bio: ""
community_role: ""
display_name: ""
email: ""
facebook: ""
first_name: "Sarah"
headshot: ""
instagram: ""
job_title: ""
last_name: ""
linkedin: ""
mentee: false
mentor: true
organization_name: ""
skills: [
{user_id: 2, skill_id: 23, category_id: 1, skill: "Integrity"}
{user_id: 2, skill_id: 98, category_id: 2, skill: "Warehousing"}
{user_id: 2, skill_id: 9, category_id: 1, skill: "Communication"}
{user_id: 2, skill_id: 245, category_id: 4, skill: "Symfony"}
]
twitter: ""
user_id: 2
},{
bio: ""
community_role: ""
display_name: ""
email: ""
facebook: ""
first_name: "Kristin"
headshot: ""
instagram: ""
job_title: ""
last_name: ""
linkedin: ""
mentee: false
mentor: false
organization_name: ""
skills: [
{user_id: 4, skill_id: 23, category_id: 1, skill: "Integrity"}
{user_id: 4, skill_id: 245, category_id: 4, skill: "Symfony"}
{user_id: 4, skill_id: 9, category_id: 1, skill: "Communication"}
{user_id: 4, skill_id: 98, category_id: 2, skill: "Warehousing"}
]
twitter: ""
user_id: 4
}
```

Below is my code. It is returning all users that have one of the searchSkills(sophia, sarah, and kristin). Im wanting it to show only sarah and kristin. I am new to coding and stackoverflow, hopefully i provided enough info for some help, thanks!

`searchSkills = ['Communication', 'Integrity']`

```
results = results.filter((v) =>
    v.skills.some((skill) => searchSkills.includes(skill.skill))
  );`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results = results.filter(user => searchSkills.every(searchTerm => user.skills.some(skillObj => skillObj.skill === searchTerm)))
```

This will make sure that every item of the searchSkills array is included in the user's skills. Hopefully that works for you!
I renamed some variables to make it a little more readable :)